# using drag events to switch rectangles in a grid in windows phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've run in a bit of a pickle with my puzzle game for windows phone.

I want to change between two adjutant rectangles, both on the same grid.

The tap event was easily implemented, but implementing drag seems to be a really big pain.

I'm also using a custom user control to get the rectangles on the grid, so i need to create custom delegates before attaching events to my rectangle matrix.

I am currently using the manipulation completed and manipulation started events to implement the drag gesture, but there are a couple of problems:

1) i have to tell the difference between tap and actual drag, both which are covered by the manipulation completed event. This is the way I do it right now:

```
if (e.TotalManipulation.Translation.X == 0 && e.TotalManipulation.Translation.Y == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {do drag stuff here}
```

however, the do drag stuff here part does not seem to work, even if the transitions are different from 0; It always executes the tap event.

I am currently stacked in using manipulation events, because, as i said, I am using a custom control as an object prototype for my rectangle matrix, and i need custom delegates for that, and apparently, the GestureListener has no constructors for its event classes.

So, any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer just after posting this question.

You can actually attach a gesture listener to a custom control and create custom delegates, by sending the drag gesture event parameter from the gesture listener drag event to the delegate you create and it works.